# How to resolve dangling ${ when using StringSubstitutor?

Tags: apache-commons-text

## Test Case

```java
// Build map
Map<String, String> valuesMap = new HashMap<>();
valuesMap.put("animal", "quick brown fox");
valuesMap.put("target", "lazy dog");
String templateString = "The ${animal} jumped ${ over the ${target}.%";

// Build StringSubstitutor
StringSubstitutor sub = new StringSubstitutor(valuesMap);

// Replace
String resolvedString = sub.replace(templateString);

assertThat( resolvedString, is( "The quick brown fox jumped ${ over the lazy dog.%" ) );
```

## The Failure

- ${target} variable is not being replaced:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: is "The quick brown fox jumped ${ over the lazy dog.%"
     but: was "The quick brown fox jumped ${ over the ${target}.%"
```

Answer (score 1):

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/StringSubstitutor.html#setEscapeChar-char-

Appears there is support for some recursive processing of variables but would need to otherwise use an escape char to indicate the first ${ isn't the beginning of a variable evaluation I think.